# .eq return all select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html structure:

```
<select class="required form-control parameter-criteria" selectpicker="" data-id="2" tabindex="-98">
        <option value="1" data-content="<span class=&quot;badge-min filter d-inline-flex&quot; style=&quot;background-color:#ff0000;&quot;> </span>CRITERIO 1 [0 - 50] - CRITERIO 2" id-criteria="2">CRITERIO 1
        </option>
</select>
<select class="required form-control parameter-criteria" selectpicker="" data-id="2" tabindex="-98">
        <option value="1" data-content="<span class=&quot;badge-min filter d-inline-flex&quot; style=&quot;background-color:#ff0000;&quot;> </span>CRITERIO 1 [0 - 50] - CRITERIO 2" id-criteria="2">CRITERIO 1
        </option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to get a specific select, so I did this:

```
var select = $('.parameter-criteria[data-id=2]').eq(2);
```

this should return just the last select `.eq(2)` but if I print `select` I get both, why?

Comment: `.eq()` index start with `0` so It shouldn't return any element

Comment: For future reference: https://api.jquery.com/eq. Also note that if you provide an invalid index you get an empty object, so if you're seeing both elements then there's something wrong in your code.

Comment: `.eq(n>length)` does not return "all" - you don't get "both", you get an empty jquery object (`select.length === 0`) - there must be something else happening: https://jsfiddle.net/fp1u8zam/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `eq()` index are 0 based...like 0 for the first element, 1 for the second element and so on. You have only two matching elements but `eq(2)` looks for the third child in the list which does not exist and return all.

```js
var select = $('.parameter-criteria[data-id=2]').eq(0);
console.log(select.text().trim());
var select2 = $('.parameter-criteria[data-id=2]').eq(1);
console.log(select2.text().trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="required form-control parameter-criteria" selectpicker="" data-id="2" tabindex="-98">
        <option value="1" data-content="<span class=&quot;badge-min filter d-inline-flex&quot; style=&quot;background-color:#ff0000;&quot;> </span>CRITERIO 1 [0 - 50] - CRITERIO 2" id-criteria="2">CRITERIO 1
        </option>
</select>
<select class="required form-control parameter-criteria" selectpicker="" data-id="2" tabindex="-98">
        <option value="1" data-content="<span class=&quot;badge-min filter d-inline-flex&quot; style=&quot;background-color:#ff0000;&quot;> </span>CRITERIO 1 [0 - 50] - CRITERIO 2" id-criteria="2">CRITERIO 2
        </option>
</select>
```

Comment: @LazyStuff, you are most welcome... in all most every where index are 0 based:)

Comment: @Manum except for array :P

Comment: @LazyStuff which arrays *in javascript* are *not* zero-indexed?

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm not explained well.. I mean, Mamum said that every where index start to 0 and this is true, but if you have an array you can start the index as 1 or 2

Comment: @LazyStuff you can? are you sure?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @LazyStuff, array *index* are also 0 based...that means `arr[0]` will give you the first element from `arr`....